# specify static ip on a windows network but obtain dns automatically from router

Tags: windows, opendns

We are using OpenDNS on our router and we want all the windows clients to obtain DNS automatically from the router. The problem is that some of the client machines the ip address is to be set as static. And under the TCP/IP settings as soon as you select "Use the following IP Address", it wants you to specify the Preferred DNS Servers. I want the DNS to come automatically from the router.
Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Change the IP address to DHCP.  Add a static DHCP entry on your DHCP server.

This does cause some issues your DHCP server isn't available when the server is first booting (say after a power outage).

Answer (score 2):

You can specify that the static IP system use the same router address that you are providing via DHCP to your clients.

There is not a way that I am aware of to tell a system to have a staic IP but get the DNS server information from DHCP.

Also, you could just specify the OpenDNS server IP address directly. I doubt that the IP of the Open DNS servers ever change from 208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220.

Answer (score 1):

Why not set the DNS value to the router itself? The router should understand how to pass on or resolve DNS queries. This way you keep your DNS settings in a 'centralised' place, which makes it easier to change your DNS 'path' in the future.